# How to have multiple values for a key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a case where the same key could have different strings associated with it.

e.g. flow and wolf both have the same characters, if I sort them and use them as keys in a dictionary, I want to put the original strings as values.

I tried in a python dict as:

```
d = {}

d["flow"] = flow
d["flow"] = wolf
```

but there is only one value associated with the key.

I tried `d["flow"].append("wolf")` but that also doesn't work.

How to get this scenario working with Python dicts?

Comment: You could have the value being a List. dict["flow"] = [flow]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have multiple items in a dictionary with the same key. What you should do is make the value a `list`. Like this -

```
d = dict()
d["flow"] = ["flow"]
d["flow"].append("wolf")
```

If that is what you want to do, then you might want to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Then you can do

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d["flow"].append("flow")
d["flow"].append("wolf")
```

Comment: Good job for thinking about defaultdict

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `setdefault` method to create a list as the `value` for a `key` **even if that `key` is *not* already in the dictionary**.

So this makes the code really simple:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault(1, []).append(2)
>>> d.setdefault(1, []).append(3)
>>> d.setdefault(5, []).append(6)
>>> d
{1: [2, 3], 5: [6]}
```

Comment: i was breaking my head over such a simple approach and then i found this , really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a dict-like class that does exactly that.

```
class MultiDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self.dict[key].append(value)
        except KeyError:
            self.dict[key] = [value]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict[key]
```

Here is how you can use it

```
d = MultiDict()
d['flow'] = 'flow'
d['flow'] = 'wolf'
d['flow'] # ['flow', 'wolf']
```

Comment: Or just use `setdefault`! Much easier! But nice class anyway, +1 :)

Comment: I don't like having to rely that much on setdefault as it makes the syntax tedious, but it is a good quick fix.